# How to calculate this time?

Tags: math

I want to show some effect (animate) with the help of jQuery during the time that should be calculated based on how many results are found for a particular needle. The rule is that the effect should continue no longer than 5 minutes and at the very least be 5 seconds long.

So, here's what I do in particular. I search a database for a particular word the user inputs and count the results. Then I search a myself defined word in the same database and count the results. If there are more the latter results than the former results, I need to calculate how long to show the effect. The more the latter results found, the longer the time the effect should continue. Plus, I need to obey the rule: no longer than 5 minutes, no less than 5 seconds.

I need that to be accurate at best.

That may be a stupid question but I cannot figure out on my own how to calculate the time! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rCVnv/3/

```
$(function(){
   var firstNum = Math.random()*10000,
       secondNum = Math.random()*10000,
       result = parseInt(secondNum - firstNum),
       milli = 0;

    if(result > 0){
        if(result < 300000 && result > 5000){
            milli = result;
            $("#test").fadeOut(result);  
        }else if(result > 300000){
             milli = 300000; 
        }else if(result < 5000){
           milli = 5000;   
       }

       $("#test").fadeOut(milli);
   }

$("#result").text("Result :  " + result);
```

});

Im not really sure how you will calculate the milliseconds needed. What I do here is generate 2 random numbers, and subtract the first value from the second value. If the result is between 300000 milliseconds (5 minutes) and 5000 milliseconds, then it just fades it at that number. If it falls beyond those ranges, it sets it to either the high end or low end. Of course, if the result is negative nothing happens because value 1 was larger than value 2.

Also I used fadeOut, which can easily be replaced with animate.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intSecondsPerResult = 2;
var intAnimationDuration = intSecondsPerResult*{$intResultsCount};
if(intAnimationDuration < 5) {
    intAnimationDuration = 5;
} else if(intAnimationDuration > 300) {
    intAnimationDuration = 300;
}
```

PS: $intResultsCount contains the size of your resultset

That is what you want?